# Golang - store userID in http struct

Tags: go

I need to store the userID somewhere in the w http.ResponseWriter or the req *http.Request, so that in my handlers I can access them.
how can I do this?
this is a small demo for what I need:

```
func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    userID := w.UserID // or something like this
}
```

again this value MUST be stored in either of these variables so that I can access it in all my http handlers.
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: This seems like it might be more of session management issue than a go issue.  A common way to handle this is to set a secure session cookie after the user authenticates, then you can use that session is to fetch the user from anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could embed http.ResponseWriter into your own struct and add extra fields

```
type ResponseWriter struct{
    http.ResponseWriter
    UserID int
}
```

Now use your ResponseWriter instead of http.ResponseWriter.

I hope this helps. [Embeded Types](http://www.goinggo.net/2014/05/methods-interfaces-and-embedded-types.html)

Comment: Note that is you use this verbatim, your ResponseWriter will no longer be a `http.Hijacker`, `http.Flusher` or `http.CloseNotifier`. It's preferable to use another method to store state, like the `golang.org/x/net/context` package for example.

Comment: In addition to @JimB's comment - http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context is a simple request context implementation as well.

Comment: thanks for everyone's answer, I eventually used a different method, but never the less your answer helped me a lot, I voted up all the answers and comments.